# Alternate to hashtag or tagging a post?

Tags: content, social-interfaces, tagging, activity-feed

What is the best possible way to integrate user post (text/media) without using hashtag (ex: Twitter) or tagging (ex: Quora/SE).
I am building a social network site and I am confused with the integration of use generated post; it becomes comparatively easy to bring worldwide content searchable using hashtag or tagging but is there any other alternate?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you manage to create a new way of accomplishing this that materially improves some aspect of tagging and searching user generated content, I would advise you *not* to try and reinvent the wheel.

And, if *I* managed to create this new pattern, I certainly wouldn't be giving it away on StackExchange ;).

Comment: Last line of your answer makes complete sense to me. (+1) :) If there is any other alternate & better way then that would be the selling point of the website. I have got another way but I think I need to see how it can beat the existing systems.

Comment: Definitely test the new interaction with real users. Find a way to discover whether it improves on the existing experiences and what new usability issues it creates, if any.

Answer (score 4):

Other than placing posts into **categories** and/or searching for **keywords** in posts, there do not seem to be any (in)famous options left. The hashtag is a very powerful way to index specific data strings and simply suffices in its job.

Answer (score 1):

Natural Language Processing comes to mind. I read this primer article on Medium. Hope it is useful. https://medium.com/@mattkiser/getting-started-with-natural-language-processing-54c7c90170e0